# Using jsDoc in Notepad++

Tags: javascript, notepad++

I use notepad++ for my JavaScript development now. I am wondering if anyone has successfully integrated jsDoc with notepad++ for easy code commenting.

I was usint Aptana earlier and it was already integrated in it as ScriptDoc I believe but Aptana grew out to be painfully slow.

Comment: I don't know, but you can check out the npp-plugins project on sourceforge. We use notepad++ at work and I have some of my own plugins in the works. What I have tried for JS is Komodo edit. (Firefox recommends it for extension writing, so I tried it) I don't know if it supports doc, but it does have some nifty javascript specific autocomplete features. You might want to check it out.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It it is possible to get jsDoc to work using the NppExec plugin. The steps are pretty straightforward, and should be a lot more straightforward after you read this.

1. In NPP (I'm using v. 5.9.3) open the plugin manager
2. Install NppExec plugin. (Npp restarts, I believe)
3. Go to the NppExec menu under plugins, choose the "Execute" menu option.  A tiny scripting window opens.
4. Enter the following NppExec scriptlet:

`NPP_SAVE

cls

SET jsDocPath = e:\javascript\jsdoc

cmd /c if "$(EXT_PART)"==".js" echo "Running JSDoc" &&  $(jsDocPath)\jsDocMe.cmd $(jsDocPath) "$(FULL_CURRENT_PATH)"  "$(CURRENT_DIRECTORY)\jsDoc"

NPP_CONSOLE 0`

(the line beginning with cmd and the following line should all appear on one line...)

Explanation:  The set command sets a variable for where your jsDoc path is.
The cmd line first checks to see if the currently open file has a .js extension, and if so
it calls a .cmd file called jsDocMe.cmd, text below, passing in the jsDocPath, the full path of the current file, and the directory of the current file. The use of these variables can be seen in the .cmd file.  The text of the .cmd file is below, a simple set of batch commands that changes to the jsDoc directory, runs the jsrun.jar file, and sends output to a new jsDoc folder beneath the current working directory.

```
cd /D %1
java -jar jsrun.jar app\run.js -d=%3 -a -p -t=templates/jsdoc %2 
%3\index.html
exit
```

Comment: If using within a node environment and you have install jsDoc globally;

    NPP_SAVE
    cls
    cmd /c if "$(EXT_PART)"==".js" echo "Running JSDoc" &&  jsDoc.cmd "$(FULL_CURRENT_PATH)"
    NPP_CONSOLE 0

Answer (score 2):

Notepad++ uses Scintilla, which does not parse inside comments, so I doubt there would be any plugins doing this. (See the comments for [this feature request](https://sourceforge.net/apps/ideatorrent/notepad-plus/ideatorrent/idea/10/).)

Comment: It is possible to [write your own lexers](http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/notepad-plus/index.php?title=Plugin_Development). Still, AFAIK, there currently is none with full JSDoc support.

Answer (score 1):

I've been using N++ for JS development for years now, and I'm pretty sure there is no way to get JSDoc going, unless you write your own plugin.

You should always be aware that N++ is not an IDE. I've tested several, and I've always come to the same conclusion as you:
N++ == slim && fast; IDE == feature rich && slow;

IMHO, the IDE with the very best JSDoc support is WebStorm (commercial product).